# Declaration is only valid at file scope how to fix?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, error-handling, xcode11

I have a Problem in my swift file.
Im trying to follow a tutorial on Youtube and he doesn't get the error.
Here is the code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    
    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    private var currentLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
    
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configerLocationServices()
    }
    
    private func configerLocationServices() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        
        let status = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
        
        if status == .notDetermined {
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        } else if status == .authorizedAlways || status == .authorizedWhenInUse {
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            
            }
    }

    extension ViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate { //Error: Declaration is only valid at file scope
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        print("Did get latest Lcation")
    }
    func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {
        print("The Status changed")
    }
}

}
```

I don't know what im doing wrong, has anyone a solution?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because you have declared an extension inside your class. Move it outside the class and compiler will stop complaining

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    private var currentLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
    
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configerLocationServices()
    }
    
    private func configerLocationServices() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        
        let status = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
        
        if status == .notDetermined {
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        } else if status == .authorizedAlways || status == .authorizedWhenInUse {
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            
            }
    }
}

extension ViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        print("Did get latest Lcation")
    }
    func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {
        print("The Status changed")
    }
}
```

You have clearly confirmed to `CLLocationManagerDelegate` in your `ViewController` extension so you dont need to confirm it in class declaration (this will result in compiler giving you a warning that duplicate confirmation to protocol) so change `class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate` to `class ViewController: UIViewController`

Comment: @blue-dynamixs: Am glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `CLLocationManagerDelegate` declaration in `class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate` line. Also, make sure that you set all pairs of curly braces correctly, I mean open and close in proper places